# pip installのオプション`--timeout`と`--default-timeout`の違いを教えてください

Tags: python, pip

## 環境

- Python 3.8.6
- pip 21.1.2

## やりたいこと

TravisCIで`pip install`を実行する際、タイムアウトによる失敗を避けるため、タイムアウト時間を長めに設定したいです。

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.8"
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## 質問

`pip install`コマンドに、タイムアウトを設定するオプションが`--timeout`と`--default-timeout`の2つありました。
`--timeout`と`--default-timeout`は何が違うのでしょうか？

#### `--timeout`

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=timeout#cmdoption-timeout

> Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).

#### `--default-timeout`

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=timeout#environment-variables

`--default-timeout`は`pip install --help`に記載されていませんでした。

Comment: [ソースコードの該当部分](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py#L278)を見る限り同じですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソースコードを見る限り、`--timeout`と`--default-timeout`は同じでした。
※ @metropolis さんのコメント参照

```
timeout = partial(
    Option,
    "--timeout",
    "--default-timeout",
    metavar="sec",
    dest="timeout",
    type="float",
    default=15,
    help="Set the socket timeout (default %default seconds).",
)  # type: Callable[..., Option]
```

https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py#L278-L287